# Windows Mobile - OMA DM Configuration Service Provider in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, windows-mobile

I need to get firmware version of Windows Mobile. I found [DevDetail Configuration Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737429.aspx) that provides this details using below code. But, not sure how to run this code in **C#**. For OMA Client Provisioning, I used [ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.configuration.configurationmanager.processconfiguration.aspx). But, using same for below XML throws error. Is there any function in C# to process below file to get information?

```
<Get>
<CmdID>2</CmdID>
<Item>
   <Target>
      <LocURI>./DevDetail/FwV</LocURI>
   </Target>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. I got answer from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/d7b796f3-4bfc-4bbb-bb14-2c7f821bbe8f